# Get a dynamically created validation container to scroll with the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates

We dynamically create an error container, append it to the body, and then position it at the element that the error is for. This works great, until the user scrolls. The error container stays in the same fixed position, while the element scrolls out of the screen in the background. How can I re-position the error element, during a scroll event, to make it also scroll?

Screen shot showing what our error containers look like. Need the container to be repositioned and scroll when user scrolls so it stays with the element it is for. Currently, it stays in a fixed position.

[image: Example screen shot of an error]

Now, when the error is in a position that can be scrolled. Notice how it appears correctly.

[image: Error before scroll]

Now notice after the page is scrolled, the error is no longer staying with the element it was for. I need this element to be re-positioned correctly with the element's new position while scrolling.

[image: After scroll. Now in wrong position]

Thanks in advance!

I know it is hard to answr questions without code, but I have to be careful as this is company stuff.

Here is where I build the container inside of the "validation.js" library as part of the jsViews package for templates we are using.

```
buildContainer: function(ev)
        {
            var $targetElem = $(ev.target),
                leftX = $targetElem.offset().left,
                topY = $targetElem.offset().top,
                widthY = $targetElem.outerWidth(),
                heightX = $targetElem.outerHeight();

            var msg = $targetElem.closest("label").val();
            var appendingContainer = null;

            $targetElem.closest("label").val('');

            return $('<div/>', {
                html: '<ul>' + this.isValid + '</ul><span></span>',
                'class': 'validation-tooltip-error',
                css: {
                    top: topY - heightX,
                    left: leftX + widthY - 20
                }
            }).appendTo("body");
        }
```

Here is the CSS for the error container:

.validation-tooltip-error
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto;
      z-index: 9999999999;
    }

```
.validation-tooltip-error ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: #a9502a;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 16px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px 4px #666666;
    -webkitbox-shadow: 0 -2px 4px #666666;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 4px #666666;
}

.validation-tooltip-error span
{
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 0 solid transparent;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
   border-top: 10px solid #a9502a;
   border-top: 10px solid #a9502a;
   border-bottom: 0;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Hopefully that helps a little.

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS with us? I think it's a positioning problem in your css.

Comment: Without css can't be sure, but I guess that the error container is positoned absolute, not fixed?

Comment: @drip I think you mean his container is set to fixed

Comment: @jj689 nope I mean that currently it's absolute, if it was fixed it would have scrolled with the content, but from the images I see that this is not the case...so it's probably set to absolute.

Comment: An issue that is occurring, is that I am using the "body" tag for appending. If I can use the container the element exist in, in this example "editQuestionArea", then it scrolls with it. The problem is hunting down where this is existing in, because these containers are all scroll-able.

Comment: @drip [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdk4J/2/) a fixed element will not scroll with content

Comment: @jj689 but it's scrolling currently with the content. Or to say it more clearly the content is scrolled down and the fixed element sit fixed to the window, a.k.a scrolling with the content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could append the error closer to the input/label it points to? I usually have something like this

```
<div class = "input-row">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type = "text" />
    <span class = "error">Error</span>
</div>
```

Then I can set the error label to absolute position and the input row to relative position.

Comment: This is the normal, and good solution. I guess, I should write it to be handled this way. I did not want to cram the validation elements in the html next to the elements they for because it was jacking up the layout. Visible or not.  I will take this route I think, and update how it went.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're concerned with additional elements, maybe you could use the :before or :after elements of either the label or input. The css would pretty much be the same as if you had the error span there. But this wouldn't work if the error message has be to dynamic.

Comment: You know what, this sparked an idea. It is based off your answer, so thanks a lot for everyone here that helped out.

Comment: I mixed both of your ideas TreeTree. Thanks! When I was trying to append the error containers, it was acting incorrect. So, I removed the css for the error container from "position:absolute" to "relative", and then used "insertAfter", and works nicely. Thanks again!